# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TransformStream'

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

I'm trying to build my socket.io code
which used to build well, but now I don't know what changes caused the project build to give an error.
Apparently, TransformStream, one of the built-in libraries of node, cannot be loaded in Typescript

```
node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/index.d.ts:6:54 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TransformStream'.

6 export declare function createPacketEncoderStream(): TransformStream<Packet, any>;
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/index.d.ts:7:96 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TransformStream'.

7 export declare function createPacketDecoderStream(maxPayload: number, binaryType: BinaryType): TransformStream<Uint8Array, any>;
                                                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I put the following line in the part

```
node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/index.d.ts:6:54
```

If I enter it, the error will be fixed, but this is not a correct way.

```
import { TransformStream } from "stream/web";
```

I also tried node in "types" tsconfig.json, but it didn't help

Comment: What's the version of typescript according to `package.json`?

Answer (score 4):

I had run into same issue. I've found that the issue is with changes done in engine.io-parser@5.2.0 and above.

https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-parser/compare/5.1.0...5.2.0

Seems they introduced TransformStream there.
For now I've moved back to fixed socket.io@4.7.1 and set resolutions to         engine.io@6.5.1

```
// package.json
    ....
    "resolutions": {
        "engine.io": "6.5.1"
    }
```

Comment: Related to this bug in engine.io https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-parser/issues/136 and this pull request in DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/66710

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading it fixed the issues for me

```
npm i socket.io@4.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue after upgrading socketio and typescript to `@latest`. I had to add `"dom"` to the `lib` array in tsconfig.json so that typescript includes the dom library files in the compilation.

```json
// tsconfig.json
....
"lib": [
    ....
    "dom",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in the tsconfig add it like this
`"lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],`